# Google Material Design vs Material Design Lite

Tags: django, npm, material-design, material-design-lite

As a background I am working on a Django project where I want to use Google's Material Design. But I'm running into a lot of trouble to install the environment with npm.

I would like to know what are the pros and cons of using each one. I was reading that Google's Material design has dependencies and MDL doesn't. Am I right?!

I am wondering what is the best choice would be to use material design lite to this project. It is important to me the maintenance of the site as easy as possible. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Maybe you are missing something? What do you mean by `Google's Material Design`? Google's [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/introduction.html) is only a spec, a set of design guidelines, when MDL is an implementation of this spec, What are you looking for? Please help us to help you.

Comment: Hey, @KostasSiabanis I am pretty sure you are missing something here. It says in the in the very same page you posted: "Material Components for the web (MDC-Web) is the successor to the Material Design Lite (MDL) project.". So it would be very nice if someone who has some actual experience with both would share their opinions.

Comment: @Silver Ringvee, OP is asking us to compare Google Material Design (which is a spec) to Material Design Lite (which is an implementation of that spec), not MDC-Web to MDL (which are both implementations to that spec)

Comment: Okay, I am pretty sure he meant a comparison between MDC-Web & MDL, as that would make sense. But let's wait for his input here... If I'm correct then let's change the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, MDL is no longer supported. Though the library exists, it will no longer be expanded or troubleshot. Material Design Web is the "successor" of MDL and is where all of the focus is occurring.

Here is the difference between the two:

- MDL offers easy installation (Nuget, NPM, etc.), but limited UI customization. You can apply a specific color scheme on the MDL components before installation, and that's about it.
- Material Design Web, on the other hand, involves a more extensive installation process (as detailed on the Getting Started page), but as a result offers full components customization.